# Compile error for hifiberryos

Tags: compiling, gcc

I am trying to compile hifiberryos. I cloned the Git repository, followed the instructions and everything was OK until I compiled it when it gave me this error.

```
**arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-g++.br_real:** **fatal error**: killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
make[4]: *** [Source/WebCore/CMakeFiles/Webcore.dir/build.make:2463: Source/WebCore/CMakeFiles/WebCore.dir/_ _ /_ _/DerivedSources/WebCore/unified-sources/UnifiedSource-3a52ce78-41.cpp.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** waiting for unfinished processes....
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:918: Source/WebCore/CMakeFiles/Webcore.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [Makefile:152: all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [package/pkp-generic.mk:250: /home/matteo/buildroot-4/build/wpewebkit-2.30.3/.stamp_built] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: _all] Error 2
```

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if the build is failing because you are running out of memory. Check the output from dmesg to see if the process is being killed by the Out of Memory killer or segfaulting because of lack of memory.  One solution to try is to add more swap.

Comment: Thanks, I added 30gb of swap, now it seems ok, I was sure to have 32gb of RAM but it was only 16